# Objective C init

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, objective-c-runtime

Disclaimer, I'm new to Objective C.  But I can't find this explained.  I've seen two ways of implementing init:

```
- (id)init {

  if ([super init]) {
    return self;
  } else {
    return nil;
  }

}
```

and

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
      // do your init business here
    } 
    return self;
}
```

so let's say i have:

```
myObj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

where MyObject class is a subclass of NSObject.  in the second example, does init not return an initialized version of NSObject?  so myObj would ... how would it know what it is?  wouldn't it think it was an NSObject rather than a MyObject?

Answer (score 3):

1) First version is just wrong. `self` should be always assigned with value returned by `super` initializer, because `init<...>` of `super` can return another object upon initialization (it's not unusual BTW). Second version is actually an 'official' way to implement `init<...>` methods.

2) 'wouldn't it think it was an NSObject rather than a MyObject'. myObj *is* instance of 'NSObject' *and* instance of 'MyObject'. It's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: right, i understand it.  i mean i know what it does.  i just want to know, under the hood, how it does it.  an object of NSObject class wouldn't have the properties or methods an object of MyObject class would.  and i'd expect NSObject's init to return an NSObject.  syntactically, it confuses me.

Comment: -init returns an id, not an NSObject *.

Comment: @scriptThis: I see. But it's not `init` which creates object it's `alloc`

Comment: Since `alloc` is sent to `MyObject` class it will return `MyObject` instance. Usually `[super init]` will set up superclass part of object ('NSObject' in your case) and nothing more. If `[super init]` want to discard current instance and return another it has responsibility to return 'MyObject' instance or instance of its subclass. It's not easy to make it right, but framework classes do this AFAIK.

Comment: @hoha:  so super's init knows who called it?  knows it was MyObject, one of it's children... and returns a MyObject object, or an object of whatever type of object called it's init?  @NSResponder, yes, init is defined to return an id, but I believe id can hold any kind of object (again, i'm knew, so...), and in this case, it's an object of MyObject class.

Comment: @scriptThis: `[[MyObject alloc] init]` - creates instance of `MyObject`, then sends a `init` message to it. That's why `init` method of `MyObject` is called. `[super init]` sends a message to the same object but this time runtime have to search for a method to handle this message in superclass of `MyObject` (that's `NSObject`). Since `NSObject`'s `init` doesn't do anything special it just returns `self`. Which is still same instance of `MyObject` because we didn't change `self` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> i just want to know, under the hood, how it does it.

It's pretty simple.  99.9% of all the classes you'll *ever* write will inherit from `NSObject` in some fashion.  In the initializers, you're supposed to invoke `super`'s designated initializer and assign it to `self`.  Eventually, `[super init]` will be invoking `-[NSObject init]`.  [According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW2), that's implemented like this:

```
- (id)init {
    return self;
}
```

So *technically*, if you inherit directly from `NSObject`, you're probably safe to not do the assignation of `self = [super init];`, because you know (and you're guaranteed) that this is equivalent to: `self = self;`, which is kind of pointless. Regardless, you should leave it in for consistency's sake.

However, once you start getting further down the inheritance chain, and *especially* when you're inheriting from opaque classes (ie, a class whose .m file you do not have), then things start getting shady.  It is possible that you'll come across a class whose designated initializer looks something like this:

```
- (id) initWithFoo:(id)aFoo {
  if ([aFoo isSuperFast]) {
    [self release];
    return [[SuperFastFooWrapper alloc] initWithFoo:aFoo];
  }
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _foo = [aFoo retain];
  }
}
```

This isn't as common, but it does happen.  In this case, we're destroying `self` (`[self release]`, to balance the `alloc` call that immediately preceded this) and instead returning a different object.